# How to add a custom Kafka Connect SinkTask metrics for monitoring?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have read through this page https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/monitoring.html regarding Kafka Connect monitoring. It is not entirely clear how to define and emit my own set of metrics. For example, I want to emit the time delta between current tiemstamp and ConnectRecord timestamp within the SinkTask `put()` implementation, which gives me end-to-end latency. That is currently not defined in the list of Sink Task metrics.

How do I add custom metrics for SinkTask monitoring?

Comment: I think you can't add custom metrics directly from the Kafka Connect API, but you can still register your own java MBean that will be exposed using JMX.

Comment: Have you tried adding interceptors to the kafka clients? For example, one that does distributed tracing?

Comment: @fhussonnois can you please point me to some example of how that's done?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to implement this on your own connector or a way to make this happen out of the box given the default supplied connect metrics?